# php - prepared mysqli

Tags: php

Criei este codigo, e diz que nao encontra nenhum registo, mesmo sabendo que o registo existe e o email e a pass estao certas.

Erro e sempre "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!"

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_POST['email']));
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_POST['password']));

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM public_users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $uid, $pwd);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($uid, $pwd);
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

    if($stmt->fetch()) {

       if(password_verify($pwd, $hashed_password)) {

          echo "Combination!";

       } else {

          echo "PASSWORD Combination!";
       }

    }

} else {
    echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
}

$stmt->close();
```

onde estou errando gente?

Comment: Só vem um registo do banco? Porque se vier mais de um, ele nunca entrará no if..

Comment: esqueca isso do Limit 1, ja retirei, mas continua a dar erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os campos email e password são texto (varchar por exemplo) correto? Nesse caso,  estão faltando as aspas na sua query:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM public_users WHERE email = '?' AND password = '?' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: sim sao, algo no codigo esta mal.. ainda nao cheguei a entender...

Comment: testou usando as aspas simples nos parâmetros como coloquei na reposta? assim `'?'`

Comment: erro igual, penso nao ser dai...

Comment: sim, a declaração de parâmetros está errada, veja o comando `bind_param`, você está passando "is", ou seja, você vai passar um parâmetro interiro (i) e outro string (s), e obviamente email não é inteiro, o correto é `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uid, $pwd)`

Comment: entendi, tb vi que nao posos ter password dentro, apenas email